# when build solution its give error access denied

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

the last access/last write time on file cannot be set. access to the path is denied I[image] try to set the bin folder for unchecked as a read-only file and folder but no luck

Comment: Shut down all instances of Visual Studio and close all open tabs.

Answer (score 0):

It sees there are some problems with your Visual Studio. You can try to reinstall or update the Visual studio.

There is a same issue in the visual studio community which is resolved by downloading the higher version of VS.

You can check it:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/the-last-accesslast-write-time-on-file-xxx-cannot/520031